# Django can't find object by filter on primary key

Tags: django

I've been trying to get Django object for my template, but I can't get an object by id. It seems that this happened because I've used external table columns in my model, see:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    type_id = models.IntegerField(db_column='typeID', primary_key=True)
    name = models.TextField(db_column='typeName', blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    base_price = models.IntegerField(db_column='basePrice', blank=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'invTypes'
```

So when I try to find this object I can't filter it by id, but can access it by name or any other field

```
>>> Item.objects.all()[0].id
'0'
>>> Item.objects.filter(name='#System')[0].id
'0'
>>> Item.objects.filter(id='0')
[]
>>> Item.objects.filter(id=0)
[]
```

Thoughts? 
Thanks

Comment: use `.pk` instead. Or `type_id` as posted in the answer works too.. Note that django adds an `AutoField` if a `primary_key` is not specified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your primary key is 'type_id', not 'id'. You should look up like:

```
Item.objects.all()[0].type_id
```

Answer (score 0):

I've messed up with type_id\id, it still stays the same.
However, I've found the solution and it wasn't django one.
It seems that after import of data to sqlite DB it didn't set integer to my primary key column, so query couldn't find TEXT primary key.

I've just changed column type to INTEGER and it worked.